# Unable to fetch div value using Froala editor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, froala

I have added froala editor on my `home.html` page, but when I am trying to fetch the div's value, I am not able to get it. What is wrong in my code?

**home.html** code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form #com="ngForm">
      <div [froalaEditor] id="froala-editor-br">Hello, Froala!</div>
    <button (click)="onsubmit(com.value)">Click me</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts** code:

```
  onsubmit(value: any)
  {
    this.TAGG = $("#froala-editor-br").froalaEditor('html.get');
console.log("---");
    console.log(this.TAGG);
  }
```

On click of submit button, I see array in console.log. Below image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try changing the div to textarea. this is my code

**home.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Content</ion-label>
    <textarea [froalaEditor] formControlName="formModel" [(froalaModel)]="form.formModel"></textarea>

    <button ion-button full type="submit" color="secondary">Save</button>
  </form>
```

**Home.ts**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder:FormBuilder ) {
  this.form=this.formBuilder.group({
    formModel:['']
  });
}

onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.form.value);          
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS7oK.png)